# Debug/trace what a program is doing under windows

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I have a program that runs under windows. I only have the binary and no symbol information, and I have VS2008. When I run this program, it hangs for around 60 seconds doing something, and I would like to understand what it is doing. Under Linux, I would use ltrace, strace and gdb, but on Windows I have no experience whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to solve my problem. It's a very nice program with great filtering capabilities.